# Drupal 7 FAPI type button does not work

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-fapi

Ik am doing a very simple form where I add a button which should do some functionality, but it's not working. Altough the button is visible on the page and when I click it the page is refreshed. Can anyone see what's wrong with this code ?

```
function donation_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'wedding_article_node_form') {
        $form['add_donation'] = array(
            '#type' => 'button',
            '#submit' => array('donation_add_donation'),
            '#value' => t('Add donation'),
        );
    }
}

function donation_add_donation(&$form, &$form_state) {
    dpm('test');
    dpm($form);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `submit` type element if you want to run a submit handler. From the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#button):

> When the button is pressed, the form will be submitted to Drupal, where it is validated and rebuilt. **The submit handler is not invoked.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: the button is not related to the functionality of the form. All I want is that when the button is pressed, a php function is executed

Comment: You'll have to use a `submit` type for that...Drupal will not run the functions inside `#submit` for a `button`, as stated in the documentation. You might get away with doing it in a form validate handler though, and checking `$form_state['clicked_button']` of `$form_state['triggering_element']` to see which button was pressed

Comment: Ok, I don't understan why FAPI documents that you can use the '#submit' -> function on a 'button' type though. And then why is there even a button type ?

Comment: FAPI is giving bad infomation about this, but the answer is right though

Answer (score 0):

Try use the property "[#executes_submit_callback](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#executes_submit_callback)" and set it to TRUE

```
$form['preview'] = array(

  '#type' => 'button', 
  '#value' => t('Preview'), 
  '#weight' => 19,
  '#executes_submit_callback' => TRUE, // add this line.

);
```

Good Luck

Muhammad